# Python printing string.split without square braces

Tags: python

I have

```
cmd=arg[3:]
```

which gives for e.g.

```
['file python parameter1=5 parameter2=456 ']
```

When I am printing I want to print in the format - python file parameters..

I tried

```
print "%s %s %s" % (string.split(cmd[0])[1],string.split(cmd[0])[0],string.split(cmd[0])[2:])
```

which gives

python file ['parameter1=5 parameter2=456 ']

How can i get the parameters part printed without the square braces or the quotes?

Thanks.
For the last part how can I print

Comment: Are you trying to parse the script command-line arguments?

Comment: There is no loop in your code. Why is your question titled "Python iterating through loop"?

Comment: @alecxe - yes it is parsing command line arguments

Comment: @kindall - I just changed it back. I think by mistake I clicked on one of the suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking Python to turn a list into a string. This is why you are seeing the brackets and quotes. All you need to do is use join to make it a string again.

```
" ".join(string.split(cmd[0])[2:])
```

or if you really prefer the string module

```
string.join(" ", string.split(cmd[0])[2:])
```

I would prefer to see the code written like this if I were doing a code review:

```
fname, interp, args = cmd[0].split(" ", 2)
print "%s %s %s" % (interp, fname, args)
```

Comment: Indeed, typed them on the fly. Thanks. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like that:

```
' '.join(cmd[0].split()[2:])
```

instead of:

```
string.split(cmd[0])[2:]
```

Also, I would recommend you to use an intermediate variable to avoid to do the same split 3 times... Or even better :

```
print ' '.join(cmd[0].split(' ', 2))
```

or actually simply:

```
print cmd[0]
```

But I guess you don't want to only print it...

Answer (score 0):

Use the `format` method in preference to `%`-style string formatting.

```
print "{0[1]} {0[0]} {0[2]}".format(cmd[0].split(None, 2))
```

Comment: Which only works in 2.6 and newer. Since the OP is using the string module for split they may not have that new of an interpreter.

Comment: I think it is more likely they are unaware of the string methods, as `str.split` has been available for a *very* long time (since at least 2.2).

Comment: I agree, use ``format`` when possible. I was just pointing out that if you are going to suggest it when the OP's code looks to be based on at least older Python docs you should probably indicate that it only works on newer interpreters.

Comment: I just find extremely unlikely that anyone is using a version of Python so old that `str.split` is not available in place of `string.split`. Otherwise, I assume that unless explicitly noted, at least Python 2.6 is available.

Comment: The original comment posits that the OP is using a version of Python so old that `str.split` (introduced no later than Python 2.2 in 2001, possibly earlier--I can't find a reference) is not available and `string.split` is the only option. I'm claiming that is extremely unlikely, and since no mention of the Python version is made, that the OP has at least Python 2.6, and therefore it is not unreasonable to use `format`.